# Why is my time domain interpolation via zero-padding in frequency domain wrong?

Tags: dft, interpolation, zero-padding

Since the process can be applied in either domain to increase the sampling rate in the other domain, I am trying to apply zero-padding in frequency space to recover a 'cleaner' interpolated signal in temporal space.
To do so, I insert zero-valued frequencies in the spectrum at the location of higher frequencies, which is a common practice.

However I don't seem to recover the original signal very well (in black below) after zero-padding (in red).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# odd dimension for simplicity
n    = 19
npad = 99

x    = np.linspace(0.,4.*np.pi,n)
xpad = np.linspace(0.,4.*np.pi,npad)

f = np.cos(x) + 1j*np.sin(x)

f_fwd = np.fft.fft(f)

f_fwd_pad = np.zeros(npad,dtype=complex)

h = (n-1)//2
f_fwd_pad[0:h+1]   = f_fwd[0:h+1]
f_fwd_pad[npad-h:] = f_fwd[h+1:]

f_interpolated = np.fft.ifft(f_fwd_pad)*npad/n

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)

ax[0].plot(x,np.real(f),linestyle=None,marker='x',color='k')
ax[0].plot(xpad,np.real(f_interpolated),color='r')

ax[1].plot(x,np.imag(f),linestyle=None,marker='x',color='k')
ax[1].plot(xpad,np.imag(f_interpolated),color='r')
```

[image]

Is that result expected? Is there some fundamental understanding that I am missing?

Comment: I don't think your bin re-arrangement subscripts are correct.  Maybe use h = (n-1)/2 as a substitute to simplify.  For starters, since you are using odd (smart) the h point needs to be part of the lower range.

Comment: For context, see: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/59740/resampling-and-removing-high-frequency-noise/59741#59741  "These formulas are equivalent to taking a DFT, zero padding at the Nyquist or chopping it, then taking the inverse DFT."

Comment: You're welcome.  MG will have the same issue if he copied the code.  The bug is in dropping the bin, not in misinterpreting.  Considering the upper half to be positive frequencies is not incorrect, it is just not as "band-limited".  See my answer and comments here https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/59316/one-sided-frequency-spectrum-matlab-vs-origin/59318#59318 then follow the fluffy cloud link for a visual demonstration in the complex case.  Note that all the points get hit.  The nub of the conversation concerns the impact of splitting the Nyquist as the band limit value.

Comment: @CedronDawg mmm unless I misunderstood your comment I can confirm that the problem was considering a time domain with an overlapping discrete point in the period. Running the code of the OP with the corrected bin slices still yields the original problem.

Comment: You may have a look at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/79356 for analytic derivation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer above is correct. Just to clarify a bit further, using `x = np.linspace(0,10,5)` will produce 5 numbers from 0 **to 10 inclusively**

```
np.linspace(0,10,5)
array([ 0. ,  2.5,  5. ,  7.5, 10. ])
```

You don't want the last number because in your example the last number is the first number of the next period. A correct implementation would be:

```
periods = 4.*np.pi
x    = np.arange(0., periods, periods/n)
xpad = np.arange(0., periods, periods/npad)
```

[image: Result with appropriate period]

Comment: Please double check this:

$$ \text{h=(n-1) / 2} $$
$$ \text{f_fwd_pad[0:h+1]   = f_fwd[0:h+1]} $$
$$ \text{f_fwd_pad[npad-h:] = f_fwd[h+1:]} $$

Sort of the same issue.  I'll be deleting this comment shortly.

Comment: Ok, so the period needs to be exactly one period (or a multiple) without overlapping. And yes Cedron there was a typo in my indexes I forgot to change some of them for the 0-based indexing in python

Comment: @CedronDawg I corrected the typos in the OP thanks for spotting that

Comment: @circuitbreaker I'm replying here since your responded here and MG will see it too.  You still missed a "+1", I edited it in for you.  Python ranges don't include the last point.  You want your bin set to include bin "h".  Then the upper range starts at "h+1" as the syntax shows.

Comment: Thanks you @CedronDawg that was another mistake indeed.
So first range is DC component + h positive frequencies so 0:h+1 in python
And second range is h negative frequencies so h+1:

Comment: Well, "above" is relative! Good answer, detailed with more code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
x    = np.linspace(0.,4.*np.pi,n)
```

The period should be N+1 samples from 0 to 2pi, for n=0..N. Then take x(k) for k=0..N-1

Currently your FFT is not a pure single tone, because the sinusoid does not have a perfect period within the FFT period. And so padding with zeros would not be the correct padding. The fix above will a perfect period within the FFT period, to make padding with zero the correct padding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with MG's fix applied.  A few other tweaks, and a fluffy cloud.  The pics look fine to me.  Command line Python 2.7

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# odd dimension for simplicity
n    = 19
npad = 299

duration = 0.85*2.0*np.pi
x    = np.arange(0., duration, duration/n)
xpad = np.arange(0., duration, duration/npad)

f = np.cos(x) + 1j*np.sin(x)

f_fwd = np.fft.fft(f)

f_fwd_pad = np.zeros(npad,dtype=complex)

h = (n-1)/2
h = n - 3
f_fwd_pad[0:h+1]   = f_fwd[0:h+1]
f_fwd_pad[npad-h:] = f_fwd[n-h:]

f_interpolated = np.fft.ifft(f_fwd_pad)*npad/n

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)

ax[0].plot(x,np.real(f),marker='x',color='k')
ax[0].plot(xpad,np.real(f_interpolated),color='r')

ax[1].plot(x,np.imag(f),marker='x',color='k')
ax[1].plot(xpad,np.imag(f_interpolated),color='r')

plt.show()

plt.plot( np.real(f_interpolated), np.imag(f_interpolated) )
plt.show()
```

[image]