# What does imaginary Component of a bin's phase in the Fourier Transform mean?

Tags: fft

I have been recently working with the FFT and realized that each frequency within a bin corresponds to a phase. This concept I have no problem with because if you wanted to construct the summation of sinusoidal waves back into the original signal, you would need the phases of those sinusoidal waves.

***My Questions:***

1. **Why must there be an imaginary component to each of the bins corresponding phases?** It makes no sense to me why a phase would need an imaginary component.
2. **In reference to DSP with the FFT, how does this imagery component come into play when characterizing a signal?**

Comment: Understanding Euler's equation is essential.  Absolutely essential.

$$ e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta) $$

You can find lots about that with a simple search.  Chances are my articles on this won't be listed first, so here you go:  https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/754.php, https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1238.php.  

Also, this answer may help:  https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/59305/using-fourier-coefficients-to-reconstruct-data-in-matlab/59306#59306

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simple trigonometry.  A vector (FFT result bin) can have a magnitude and a phase.  Or you can specify the same vector identically with X,Y coordinates.  The complex representation simply uses X for the real part and Y for the imaginary component.  Without an imaginary component, there’s no place to put the Y, and your vector would be under specified.

The phase ends up being atan2(I,Q) == atan2(Y,X) == atan2(im(z),re(z))

As for why use a complex representation rather than 2 strictly real quantities?  The complex math is more elegant, and requires less writing on the chalkboard to demonstrate similar things.

Comment: It appears I misunderstood what a bin is. I thought it was just a sin wave with a specific frequency and with a specific phase. My understand was the summation of these different sine waves was a approximation of the original signal.

Comment: Also, since I wording with a signal shouldn't the imaginary competent(y component) be 0?

Comment: Yes, you are exactly right, the bin result is a sinewave with a magnitude and phase is a vector requiring 2 components to specify.  If the imaginary component is zero, the phase is also stuck at zero.  A sinewave basis vector is strictly odd.  Therefore you need a phase or cosine component if your FFT input consists of any even symmetry (e.g. isn’t strictly anti-symmetric).